# Efficient oblivous test of plaintext equality for pairs of sets

Tags: elgamal-encryption, blinding

Suppose we have two sets of ElGamal cipher texts encrypted with the same public key $y$ in a prime order group:

$C_i = (g^{r_i}, a_i y^{r_i}) $ for $ i \in \{1 ... n\}$

and

$D_j = (g^{s_j}, b_j y^{s_i}) $ for $ j \in \{1 ... m\}$

Bob own the private key $x$ to $y$ such that $g^x = y$

Alice wants to know if there is any intersection between the two sets of plaintexts $ \{a_1,... a_n\}$ and $ \{b_1,... b_m\}$ , i.e. if there exists $i, j$ such that $a_i = b_j$, but without revealing to either alice or bob any other information about the two sets or their individual elements.

One way to do this is by performing [an oblivious test of plaintext equality](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9527/how-does-an-oblivious-test-of-plaintext-equality-work)  for every pair of $C_i, D_j$. This requires $O(m*n)$ exponentiations in the blinding phase. I want to propose a protocol that only requres $O(m + n)$ exponentiations in the blinding phase.

My question is, would the following protocol work? Is it safe/unsafe and does it leak any information?

Protocol:

Alice samples a random $S$ from $\mathbb{Z}_q$ and exponentiates (aka blinds) each ciphertext from both sets:

$(g^{r_iS}, a_i^S y^{r_iS}) $

and

$(g^{s_jS}, b_j^S y^{s_iS}) $.

Alice then computes every division of pairs of ciphertexts from the sets:

$(g^{s_jS - r_iS}, b_j^S a_i^{-S} y^{s_jS - r_iS}) $

and the rest of protocol proceeds as a Chaum-Pederson protocol for each pair of elements.

So essentially, the instead of doing a division for every pair of ciphertexts and then blinding the encrypted quotient, we first blind each ciphertext with the same blinding factor ($S$) and then perform all the divisions.